# Manually trigger Karma to rerun tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

I know that Karma has a built-in `autoWatch` option that will cause my tests to be rerun when a test file changes:

```
var server = new karmaServer({
    autoWatch: true,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 250,
});
server.start();
```

Is there a way to trigger this rerun manually?  I would like to have more control over when my tests are rerun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a bit more about Karma and discovered [`karma.runner.run()`](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html), which triggers an already-running server (for example, a Karma server you started in a different command window) to rerun its tests.  In my gulp task I now do something like this:

```
gulp.task('run-tests', function() {
    gulp.watch('/glob/to/my/files').on('change', function() {
        karma.runner.run({ configFile: 'karma.conf.js' });
    });    
});
```

Note that if you run this task from the same process that spawned your Karma server, you will see duplicate test results since both the server *and* the runner report their results to the command line.  To only show one set of test results, you can start your Karma server in a background process using [something like this](https://github.com/callmehiphop/karma-background).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run it manually with gulp, just make a task from it (I assume that you want to re-run server.start):

```
var server = new karmaServer({
 autoWatch: true,
 autoWatchBatchDelay: 250,
});

gulp.task('runTests', function() {
 server.start(); 
});
```

And then whenever you need to run test, run in command line:

```
gulp runTests
```

Comment: I think this will either restart the Karma server or cause a second Karma server to run.  I'm looking for way to cause the existing Karma server to reload its source files and rerun the tests - similar what `autoWatch: true` does - only manually.